# Any ready made script to pin the IRQ to the optimal CPU?

Tags: cpu, interrupt

I'm not a expert by any means and I worry about doing wrong stuff... is there a standard / approved way to just run a script and have my interrupt tuned correctly on ubuntu 18.04 ?

I also have thousands of machines to do this so I really don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I'm following amd instructions https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/56224.pdf

Comment: Bit confused there – so you want to manually pin the IRQ to CPU cores local to your NIC(s), but if you do that, what does irqbalance have to do with it? Or are you observing what irqbalance does, which should be pinning IRQs to the CPU core on which they'd have the least cache miss rate, but have a way of telling that this is suboptimal for your application?

Comment: I want to manually pin the IRQ to the optimal CPU core with a script, that is reliable and can do that in thousand of machines at same time

Comment: so, do you know how to do it on *one* machine? And if you manually pin it, what has `irqbalance`, which you explicitly include in your title, got to do with it?

Comment: I edited the title, see if it's better